# Factory Girl building and creating 3 related models, association is lost after build stage

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot

I have the following models

```
class Company
  has_many :admins, class_name: 'Profile::CompanyAdmin'

  validates :must_have_at_least_one_admin_validation

  def must_have_at_least_one_admin_validation
    errors.add(:admins, :not_enough) if admins.size.zero?
  end
end

class Profile::CompanyAdmin
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :company_admin_profiles
end

class User
  has_many :company_admin_profiles, inverse_of: :user
end
```

I am trying to set up factories so I can easily build coherent data. Especially, I want to be able to `create(:company, *traits)` and it creates an Admin profile with a user account

```
factory :company do 

  transient do
    # need one admin to pass validation
    admins_count 1          # Admins with a user account
    invited_admins_count 0  # Admins without user account
  end

  after(:build) do |comp, evaluator|
    # Creating a company admin with a user
    comp.admins += build_list(:company_admin_user,
      evaluator.admins_count,
      company: comp
    ).map { |u| u.company_admin_profiles.first }
    comp.admins += build_list(:company_admin_profile,
      evaluator.invited_admins_count,
      company: comp
    )
    comp.entities = build_list(:entity,
      evaluator.entity_count,
      company: comp
    )
    # If I debug here, I have
    # comp.admins.first.user # => Exists !

  end

  after(:create) do |comp, evaluator|
    # If I debug here
    # comp.admins.first.user # => Gone 

    # First save users of admin profiles (we need the user ID for the admin profile user foreign key)
    comp.admins.map(&:user).each(&:save!)
    # Then save admins themselves
    comp.admins.each(&:save!)
  end
```

In the example above, when I debug at the end of the company `after_build` stage, I have successfully built admin profiles with thier users, however after the beginning of the `after_create` stage, I have lost the associated user in the admin profiles (cf comments)

What's wrong ?

For the reference here are the other factories for Profile/User

```
factory(:company_admin_user) do 

  transient do 
    company { build(:company, admins_count: 0) }
  end

  after(:build) do |user, evaluator|
    user.company_admin_profiles << build(:company_admin_profile,
      company: evaluator.company,
      user: user,
    )
  end

  after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
    user.rh_profiles.each(&:save!)
  end

end

factory :company_admin_profile, class: Profile::CompanyAdmin do
  company
  user nil # By default creating a CompanyAdmin profile does not create associated user
end
```

EDIT :

A simpler way to see the problem

company = FactoryGirl.build(:company)
company.admins.first.user # => Exists !
company.save # => true
company.admins.first.user # => Nil !

Comment: @mudasobwa just read the opposite on the FactoryGirl documentation
> Calling create will invoke both after_build and after_create callbacks.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks

I confirmed this when placing breakpoints in the code. Maybe this was the case in an older version of FG but not now

Comment: Uh, indeed, I was referring to the obsolete version of FG. Will remove the comment above, since it’s irrelevant.

Comment: Would you mind to try to explicitly _reload_ the respective objects? Like `comp.reload.admins.first.reload.user`?

Comment: Just tried that after a FactoryGirl.create(), it still gives nil

Comment: Then probably the problem is with model relations, not FG itself. `company.save` does not seem to save nested users. Try it outside FG.

Comment: Yes most likely. In case it's relevant I am using Mongoid. I have found a fix which is to use a before_create hook to save users, since the company will not have been persisted yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem saving the company model first loses the 2-level deep nested user association. SO instead of

```
after(:create) do |comp, evaluator|
  # First save the users
  comp.admins.map(&:user).compact.each(&:save!)

  # Then save admins themselves
  comp.admins.each(&:save!)
```

The following does work (still not quite sure why though)

```
before(:create) do |comp, evaluator|
  # Need to save newly created 2-level deep nested users first
  comp.admins.map(&:user).compact.each(&:save!)
end

after(:create) do |comp, evaluator|
  # Then save admins themselves
  comp.admins.each(&:save!)
end
```

Comment: This obviously works, but the nested model should be saved within a parent when configured properly.